# What is the correct terminology to describe this kind of program/algorithm that calls on students randomly, but fairly?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, random, data-structures

As a teacher, I would like to design a program that helps me call on students randomly. A random number generator is not good enough because a few students might seldom get called on this way. I do not want a randomized queue generator either because then a student I have just called on can confidently stop paying attention until I call on the rest of her classmates.

Ideally, I could use some sort of program that calls on Students 1-10 on a random queue, but that occasionally deviates from that queue to call on previously called students. This would ensure that all students are called on reasonably frequently, but also that the student most recently called on won't get complacent that I won't call on him again for a while. For example, random output like this would be what I need: 5, 7, 2, 1, 1, 9, 10, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 4...

What is the correct terminology to describe this kind of program? I am not necessarily looking for an answer on how to write such code, although that would be nice too.

Comment: I realize it's just an analogy, but my first thought is that this is a terrible teacher who needs to look up from the computer screen from time to time and actually pay attention to the students...

Comment: [Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) algorithm. I think you have described fair and round-robin scheduling algorithms.

Comment: The best thing I can think of for your situation is to: Store a list of all students and the number of times each of them were called in the past. You can create a program that randomly chooses a student from the entire list of students, but the probability of calling on any particular student is less likely the more times they have been called on already. This way, all students are (roughly) called on the same amount of times, but doesn't guarantee that any single student won't be called on again shortly after they were just called.

Comment: "A random number generator is not good enough because a few students might seldom get called on this way" As far as I know, both `java.util.Random` in Java and `System.Random` in C# can generate a _uniformly distributed_ sequence of random numbers. What you are saying won't happen.

Comment: @Sweeper: "What you are saying won't happen." That's true in the long run. But over a short period of time, it *will* happen. For example, write a loop that uses the random number generator to generate all numbers from 1 to 20. You might be surprised to find that it sometimes takes more than 50 iterations before all 20 numbers are generated. Some numbers will be generated more than 3 times before the last number is generated once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select students from a pool of calls where each student is represented a certain number of times. To smooth out call nonuniformity, the number of occurrences in this pool is higher for students that were chosen less often and smaller for students that were chosen more often but is never less than 1 to give a chance to any student to be called on again at any time, irregardless of his "call history". Initially, each student is represented exactly once in the pool. The below implementation allows hot inclusion/exclusion of students. The generator is provided by the `nextCall()` method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class StudentCalls {
    private final Set<String> students = new HashSet<>();
    private final List<String> callPool = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Random rand = new SecureRandom();

    public void addStudent(String name) {
        int studentCount = students.size();
        if (!students.add(name))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " has already been added");
        int newStudentCalls = studentCount == 0 ? 1 // bootstrap
                // average of already present students', never less than 1
                : (int) Math.round((double) callPool.size() / studentCount);
        for (int i = 1; i <= newStudentCalls; i++)
            callPool.add(name);
    }

    public void addStudents(String... names) {
        for (String name : names)
            addStudent(name);
    }

    public void removeStudent(String name) {
        if (!students.remove(name))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown student: " + name);
        callPool.removeAll(Collections.singleton(name));
    }

    public String nextCall() {
        int poolSize = callPool.size();
        if (poolSize == 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No students to choose from");
        int poolIndex = rand.nextInt(poolSize);
        /* Below is optimized equivalent of this code:
        String selectedStudent = callPool.remove(poolIndex);
        if (!callPool.contains(selectedStudent))
            callPool.addAll(students);
        */
        String selectedStudent = callPool.get(poolIndex);
        if (Collections.frequency(callPool, selectedStudent) > 1) {
            String lastInPool = callPool.remove(--poolSize);
            if (poolIndex < poolSize)
                callPool.set(poolIndex, lastInPool);
        } else
            for (String student : students)
                if (!student.equals(selectedStudent))
                    callPool.add(student);
        return selectedStudent;
    }

    public void conductClasses(int numberOfCalls) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++)
            System.out.println(nextCall());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentCalls sc = new StudentCalls();
        sc.addStudents("Josh", "Cooper", "Rachel", "Buckley", "Matt",
                "Lucy", "Kristin", "Kyle", "Kelly");
        sc.conductClasses(20);
        sc.removeStudent("Matt");
        sc.conductClasses(15);
        sc.addStudent("Cliff");
        sc.conductClasses(25);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) 
Example:

```
public class Program {

    static void shuffle(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int randomValue = i + random.nextInt(n - i);
            int randomElement = array[randomValue];
            array[randomValue] = array[i];
            array[i] = randomElement;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        shuffle(values);

        // Display elements in array.
        for (int value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirement that once a student is called on that they can be complacent while all other students are called on.

Comment: depends how you use it, if you input all students 3 times in your array, shuffle the array and start calling the students according that order, then nobody can idle.

Comment: Nice - this is what Apple used to make music 'shuffle' seem more 'human' random. https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/why-random-shuffle-feels-far-from-random-10066621.html

Comment: Would there be a more efficient way than the following to input all students all 3 times in the array? int[] values = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ... }?

Comment: If efficiency is an issue, then you better go with a round roubin-like algorithm like the others suggested. Although i find this shuffle better because you can put an upper cap how many times one student can be selected. With the other solutions you can select the same student over and over again, and the fairness is not guaranteed.